# Docker Relocate to external USB SSD Problem

Tags: mount, ssd, docker

Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Docker version 24.0.2

I am trying to relocate the /var/lib/docker directory to my USB SSD flash drive to save memory on the internal storage, however, I am having difficulty doing so.
I have attempted to modify the docker service to set a different data-root, but when I start the service, I get an error and think this is relates to the fact that the relocate destination is a USB flash drive.

I created a copy of the existing docker files by executing

```
sudo rsync -avxP /var/lib/docker/ /home/myuser/riva/docker/
```

where /home/myuser/riva is my mounted USB drive (myuser is my username), and then modified docker.service to set the data root to the new location

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --data-root /home/myuser/riva/docker -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

However, docker fails to start, producing the following error

```
time="2024-03-13T02:21:33.996540964-07:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
time="2024-03-13T02:21:34.000771936-07:00" level=info msg="detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
time="2024-03-13T02:21:34.100456272-07:00" level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: invalid argument" storage-driver=overlay2
time="2024-03-13T02:21:34.100577936-07:00" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver overlay2 failed: driver not supported"
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

For test purposes, I tried the same procedure to relocate to another folder on internal storage and this worked well, so this proves the issue relates to the SSD Flash drive.
When I execute ‘fdisk -l‘, the result reports ntfs, as expected.

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="RIVA" UUID="18089E33089E103C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="5fa27c32-117b-4223-9a76-6297b0fdc625"
```

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see release details; nor how you installed docker, and importantly if your $USER (username) is actually `myhome`, or that's just a directory name (ie. no user exists of that name) OR another user.  I suspect your *internal storage* may not have been NTFS, thus the issue may also be *fs* related (*rather than directory location/permissions related*)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've updated the post to include version info and rename myhome to myuser and making it clear that myuser is the user. Internal storage is ext4 and external sforage is NTFS.

Comment: I'll suggest you apply security fixes asap as you're a year+ behind (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.6, but installed systems upgraded before that date); your image is very oudated. You've not provided docker app clues as required; but if *confined* app you can't access directories outside of $HOME thus my comment & you didn't specify what local storage (ie. was it readable to confined apps?). Why not try a POSIX *fs* on storage IF it's accessible to apps running *confined* (if applicable to your unstated docker app install)

Comment: Thanks. Switching to ext4 fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. The problem was that storage-driver=overlay2 was not compatible with the NTFS file system. I re-formatted my flash drive to be ext4 and this resolved my issue. I hope someone can benefit from my issue.

For info, prior to formatting my flash drive, I changed storage-driver=fuse-overlayfs but this also failed with the NTFS file system. I also tried VFS, and docker successfully worked, but resulted in an excessively high download.